# how to implement System.Data.Linq.DataContext for oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, linq

```
public class DatabaseContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
```

I am using `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` for my existing code which is pointing to SQL Server, but when I changed the connectionstring pointing to Oracle I got

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' Additional
>   information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred.

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using System.Data.SqlClient namespace with Oracle. SqlClient is only for Sql Server. 
You need to use the Oracle .NET client which you can get from the Oracle website.

Comment: i am  using Enterprise library. i didn't use System.Data.SqlClient namespace

Comment: Your error "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred." indicates that you are using System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq;


namespace Cbv.AGoall.Sudha.Repositories.DatabaseContexts
{

    
    public class UserlDatabaseContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext